# Mistake in keyboard typing by Digispark

Tags: digispark

I want to open notepad by my Digispark. I use this code:

```cpp
/*  * Generated with <3 by Dckuino.js, an open source project !  */

#include <avr/pgmspace.h>
#include "DigiKeyboard.h"

const char line1[] PROGMEM = "notepad.exe";
const char line2[] PROGMEM = "Hello World!";

char buffer[256];

#define GetPsz(x) (strncpy_P(buffer, (char*)x, 256))
#define KEY_UP_ARROW      0x52
#define KEY_DOWN_ARROW    0x51
#define KEY_LEFT_ARROW        0x50
#define KEY_RIGHT_ARROW       0x4F
#define KEY_LEFT_GUI          0xE3
#define KEY_ESC               0x29
#define KEY_TAB               0x2B

void digiBegin() {
  DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(0,0);
  DigiKeyboard.delay(50);
}

void digiEnd() {
  const int led=1;
  pinMode(led, OUTPUT);
  while (1) {
    digitalWrite(led, !digitalRead(led));
    DigiKeyboard.delay(1000);
  }
}

void printText(char *txt) {
  DigiKeyboard.print(txt);
  DigiKeyboard.update();
}

void setup() {
  digiBegin();

  DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_R,MOD_GUI_LEFT);

  DigiKeyboard.delay(50);

  // notepad.exe   printText(GetPsz(line1));

  DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_ENTER);

  DigiKeyboard.delay(100);

  // Hello World!   printText(GetPsz(line2));

  digiEnd();
} /* Unused endless loop */ void loop() {}
```

My program opened RUN Windows, but instead of typing "notepad.exe" it types "fgl]hY&]p]" and I don't know where am I am making mistakes. Please help me.

I have to write my code similar this:

```cpp
#include "DigiKeyboard.h"

int pinled = 1;

void setup()
{
    pinMode(3, INPUT);

    digitalWrite(3, HIGH);
}


void loop()
{
    DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(0);

    if(digitalRead(3) == LOW)
    {
        DigiKeyboard.sendKeyPress(KEY_R, MOD_GUI_LEFT);
        DigiKeyboard.delay(10);

        DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(0, 0);

        DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_C);
        DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_M);
        DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_D);
        DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_ENTER);

        DigiKeyboard.delay(500);

        DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_I);
        DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_P);
        DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_C);
        DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_O);
        DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_N);
        DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_F);
        DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_I);
        DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_G);
        DigiKeyboard.sendKeyStroke(KEY_ENTER);
    }
}
```

Comment: What keyboard layout do you have active on your PC?

Comment: I tried to clean up the question a bit. You have `// notepad.exe   printText(GetPsz(line1));`, but I'm guessing these are two separate lines in the code you're actually running; likewise for `line2`.

Comment: when debugging code like yours, always print strings like `1111122222233333` or `aaabbbccc` .... that way you can tell if characters repeat, even if they are the wrong characters ... in your example, one character appears to repeat, but it us uncertain